# How do I get all user input as a string with my discord bot after they type a certain command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot made with python. I want it to retrieve everything typed after a user types the !loot command, and then store the number given in a text file based on the string/fruit given.

For example, if someone types !loot 100 apples, 200 oranges, 300 plums, I would get the user input "100 apples, 200 oranges, 300 plums" in python as a string.

My idea after getting this string is to split the string based on commas into a list,so the list would look like [100 apples, 200 oranges, 300 plums]. After this I could check if the keyword matches a text file and if it does extract number and put it in the file.

I tried

```
async def loot(ctx, message):
    messagelist = [x.strip() for x in message.split(',')]
    await bot.say(messagelist)
```

but the bot only gives the first part,which would be [100] in the above example.

tldr: take multiple item/number pairs separated by commas and put each number in a different text file based on if the items name matches the file name.

Answer (score 1):

A [feature of discord.py's commands extension framework](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments) makes this easy

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def loot(ctx,*,message):
    await bot.say(message)
```

If you notice the `*`, it tells the library to put everything the user types after it into `message` as a string.